# RDLC Report: Large empty spaces appearing at page top

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reporting-services, report, rdlc

I'm designing a report that contains basically only textboxes and lines where text should be printed. However, once I run the report with actual data, large empty spaces (of varying sizes) are added on top of every page, above the content that should be at the top. As you can see in the image below, it's designed so that there's no space above the textbox with user information. The report doesn't contain a header, ConsumeContainerWhitespace is turned on, there are only bottom margins, size of the body is within the A4 page parameters (21 x 29.7 cm) and I've tried every other option found here (changing interactive size, too) with no luck so far.

[Report in the designer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9EUg.png)

[Report PDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gjkCj.png)

Comment: Have you tried setting the "Consume container whitespace" property to True?

Comment: Like I said in the post above, yes.

Comment: what if you design your report to have a tablix with no detail row and all your data inside the tablix cells instead of free text boxes? What if you set "Can Grow" property of the user info to false?